# Have Banshee change folder structures inside music folder after editing MP3 meta-data

Tags: banshee, metadata

If I edit say an artist name inside Banshee that uses an alternative spelling in order to merge the folder with the other folder for the same artist using the correct spelling of the artist's name, it doesn't affect my music folder.

But I want the changes I make to the MP3's meta-data to take effect inside my music folder. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Banshee to rename your folders when you update metadata, you need to go into Banshee's preferences (`Edit > Preferences`) and enable "Update file and folder names".

[image]